# Javascript Array Difference with Different Initialization Method

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

Can someone explain to me why the following happens in Javascript Console (Node 7.2.0):

Array in example I has different behavior than example II and III

**EXAMPLE I**

```
> var x = new Array(3).fill(new Array(2).fill(0))
> x
[ [ 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0 ] ]
> x[0][0] = 1;
> x
[ [ 1, 0 ], [ 1, 0 ], [ 1, 0 ] ]
```

**EXAMPLE II**

```
> var y = [...new Array(3)].map(()=>{return [...new Array(2)].map(()=>0)})
> y
> [ [ 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0 ] ]
> y[0][0] = 1
> [ [ 1, 0 ], [ 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0 ] ]
```

**EXAMPLE III**

```
> var y = []
> y.push([ 0, 0 ])
> y.push([ 0, 0 ])
> y.push([ 0, 0 ])
> y
> [ [ 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0 ] ]
> y[0][0] = 1
> [ [ 1, 0 ], [ 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0 ] ]
```

It seems that different ways to initialize array will cause different behaviors of an array. I'm confused and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`array.fill()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) returns the modified array, so you're filling an array with multiple references to the same array. That is why when you modify it in one place, it automatically shows up in the other places.

The first example is equivalent to doing something like:

```
var arr = [ 0, 0 ];
var x = [ arr, arr, arr ];
```

Comment: I don't think so, I specifically used the new operator to create a new array for fill function to avoid using the same reference.

Comment: `new Array()` creates a single array *once*. `array.fill()` does not make copies, it just assigns the array elements to whatever you pass to it (which in this case is a single array).

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the difference is that in JS, objects (including arrays) are not copied, they are linked. In example I, you fill the array with a single array.

```
> var x = new Array(3).fill(new Array(2).fill(0))
// You have filled x with three links to the same array
> x
[ [ 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0 ] ]
> x[0][0] = 1;
// You have now modified the actual array, this change is reflected in all the links to it.
> x
[ [ 1, 0 ], [ 1, 0 ], [ 1, 0 ] ]
```

What you are doing is the same as doing:

```
var a = [ 0, 0 ]
var x = [ a, a, a ]
```

OR

```
var a = [ 0, 0 ]
var x = []
x.push(a)
x.push(a)
x.push(a)
```

---

BTW, using `new Array()` is generally a bad practice. There is no benefit over the array literal syntax. Also, using `new Array(n)` makes "empty slots" in your array, which is *very odd* and can cause problems in your programs if you don't fill all the slots.